# Hibernate Envers do not generates revisions with spring boot

Tags: spring, spring-boot, hibernate-envers

I am trying to use Hibernate envers to generate revisions of my data in the database. I added the @Audited on my entities. The tables are generated in the db but there are no revisions generated when I change the data.

I am using Spring 1.5.6.RELEASE and  Hibernate Version 5.2.9. I use CrudRepository to update the database. Here is my Entity:

```
@Entity
@Audited
@Inheritance(strategy = InheritanceType.JOINED)
@Table(name = "table")
@Getter
@Setter
@NoArgsConstructor
public class Unit implements Serializable {

  @Column(name = "type", nullable = false)
  @Enumerated(EnumType.STRING)
  public Type type;

  @Id
  @GeneratedValue(generator = "uuid")
  @GenericGenerator(name = "uuid", strategy = "uuid2")
  @Column(name = "suid")
  private String suid;

  @Column(name = "label")
  private String label;

  @Column(name = "extAddressID")
  private String extAddressID;
}
```

This is my configurations:

```
platform: postgres
    initialize: true
    driver-class-name: org.postgresql.Driver

  jpa:
    database-platform: org.hibernate.dialect.PostgreSQLDialect
    show-sql: true
    format-sql: true
    use_sql_comments: true
    hibernate:
      ddl-auto: update
    properties:
      hibernate.dialect: org.hibernate.dialect.PostgreSQLDialect
      hibernate.type: trace
      hibernate.show_sql: true
      hibernate.format_sql: true
      hibernate.use_sql_comments: false


      org.hibernate.envers.audit_table_suffix: _vo
      org.hibernate.envers.default_schema: versioned_object
      org.hibernate.envers.audit_strategy: org.hibernate.envers.strategy.ValidityAuditStrategy
      org.hibernate.envers.revision_field_name: begin_lifespan_version
      org.hibernate.envers.audit_strategy_validity_end_rev_field_name: end_lifespan_version
      org.hibernate.envers.audit_strategy_validity_store_revend_timestamp: true
```

Comment: Can you post one of your entity mappings and how you're modifying the entity?  Just saying that it does not work and posting configuration doesn't necessarily given adequate information.  You say the tables are being generated, so at least Envers is building its mapping, so it must be something happening during transaction time.  Posting the entity mapping & your code where you change the entity may help narrow down the issue.

Comment: Thanks for your comment. I updated the post.

Comment: I assume you're calling the `CrudRepository` method inside a transaction?

Comment: Yes, I have a simple service on top of the repository that calls repository.save ()

Comment: Did you ever resolve this?

Comment: no :(, I gave up on it.

Comment: If you could, could you share your spring-boot app either via github or open a jira and attach a sample that shows this doesn't work.  I'd really like to understand why this does not work under spring-boot since we don't see this being a problem without spring.